# Возможно ли вывести результат цикла for в шаблон Twig?

Tags: php, twig

```
$x = 0;
while ($x < 10)
{
    $x++;
}
```

В шаблоне `{{ x }}` выводит только последнее число.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эмн...
Этот код бессмысленен - можно просто взять и присвоить `$x` десятку.

Если нужен массив чисел, то как-то так:

```
<? // PHP
$x = range(1, 10);

// Twig
{% for num in x %}
<div>{{ num }}</div>
{% endfor; %}
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ.

Comment: десятку же

Comment: Чойта?  
Хотя... Да, итераций будет девять, но последняя итерация инкрементирует на ещё одну единицу...  
Каюсь, невнимательно посмотрел, код-то всё-равно бессмысленный в данном случае, так что не ссуть важно какое значение останется :)